# Add Custom form action in Elementor Pro Form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, elementor

I want to add a cusom form action in **Action After Submit** dropdown in elementor pro.
I tried to add a action in my **functions.php** but nothing worked.

This is my code:

```php
class CustomFormAction extends \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Action_Base {
    public function get_name() {
        return 'translate-action';
    }

    public function get_label() {
        return __( 'Translate Action', 'elmformaction' );
    }

    /**
     * @param \Elementor\Widget_Base $widget
     */
    public function register_settings_section( $widget ) {
        $widget->start_controls_section(
            'section_translate',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Translate Action', 'elmformaction' ),
                'condition' => [
                    'submit_actions' => $this->get_name(),
                ],
            ]
        );

        $widget->add_control(
            'success_image',
            [
                'label' => __( 'Success Image', 'elmformaction' ),
                'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::MEDIA,
                'label_block' => true,
                'separator' => 'before',
                'description' => __( 'Select the image to be displayed after the form is submitted successfully.', 'elmformaction' ),
            ]
        );

        $widget->end_controls_section();
    }

    /**
     * @param \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Form_Record $record
     * @param \ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Classes\Ajax_Handler $ajax_handler
     */
    public function run( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
        $settings = $record->get( 'form_settings' );

        if ( empty( $settings['success_image'] ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $ajax_handler->add_response_data( 'success_image', $settings['success_image']['url'] );
    }

    public function on_export($element) {}
}
```

This is the code from the article i have edited it to my needs but the option is not showing in elementor.

I want to add an action [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9NM0.png)

I was following an artical [How to Code Custom Elementor Form Actions](https://www.soliddigital.com/blog/how-to-code-custom-elementor-form-actions), but this article is very unclear like where should i make change to achive this task etc.

And i added the above code into a new file in `wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/forms/actions/translate.php` but it doesent helped much

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the SolidDigital article you posted is not very clear.

As per **Elementor's own guide** on writing Custom Actions [here](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/form-actions/advanced-example/) -

They specify the folder structure of the php files that include your own custom action, but as you may see, they don't mention where to put these files, however I was able to solve this after some more research.

I renamed the folder structure a bit to fit your action **based on your example**, as follows:

```
elementor-forms-translate-action/
|
├─ form-actions/
|  └─ translate.php
|
└─ elementor-forms-translate-action.php
```

As seen here there should be two files, not only one `translate.php` file.

The `translate.php` file should include your custom action code as you mentioned above, and the `elementor-forms-translate-action.php` file is the one that registers the new action.

This should be the content of the `elementor-forms-translate-action.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Elementor Forms Translate Action
 * Description: Description of the action
 * Plugin URI:  https://elementor.com/
 * Version:     1.0.0
 * Author:      Elementor Developer
 * Author URI:  https://developers.elementor.com/
 * Text Domain: elementor-forms-sendy-action
 *
 * Elementor tested up to: 3.7.0
 * Elementor Pro tested up to: 3.7.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

/**
 * Translate action.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @param ElementorPro\Modules\Forms\Registrars\Form_Actions_Registrar $form_actions_registrar
 * @return void
 */
function add_new_translate_form_action( $form_actions_registrar ) {

    include_once( __DIR__ .  '/form-actions/translate.php' );

    $form_actions_registrar->register( new CustomFormAction() );

}
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/actions/register', 'add_new_translate_form_action' );
```

**Pay attention** that this file calls the `CustomFormAction` class to register the action.

I would recommend to change the `CustomFormAction` class name to something less generic such as `TranslateFormAction` on both php files.

After you performed these changes, you need to zip the `elementor-forms-translate-action` folder, conserving folder structure, and upload the zip file in Wordpress Plugins area in the WP admin dashboard, just as you would with a new plugin, and don't forget to activate it.

For more information, coding standards and best practices go to Elementor's addon guide [here](https://developers.elementor.com/docs/addons/).